# Is it possible to list all the mutexes in the system?

Tags: linux, mutex, semaphore

Using ipcs command we can list the semaphores, shared memories etc, but not mutexes. Is there any way to list the mutexes in the system? If yes, is there a way to release them using some command? (like ipcrm command can be used to clean the semaphores).

Thank-you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On linux, mutex implemented via futex, using `/proc/pid/syscall` interface you can find out which process have locked by mutex thread, using script like this one
https://gist.github.com/amr/722145

Comment: Is it possible to clear these mutexes? like ipcrm command can be used to clean the semaphores...